# dissoc with pred

Tags: clojure

`(dissoc :a m)` allows me to dissoc a given key. However is there a way to use a predicate function to dissoc any key for which the pred is true ? `(dissoc-with-pred pred? m)`

So given a map - `{:a 2 :b 3 :c 1 :d 4}` `(dissoc-with-pred (fn [[kv]] (> v 2) m)` will return `{:a 2 :c 1}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 1

```
(defn dissoc-with-pred [f m]
  (reduce-kv (fn [res k v] 
               (if (f k v) 
                 (assoc res k v)
                 res))
             {} m))
```

**Edit.**

Version 2 (suggested by Chouser)

```
(defn dissoc-with-pred [f m]
  (reduce-kv (fn [m k v]
               (if (f k v)
                 m
                 (dissoc m k)))
             m m))
```

Version 3

```
(defn dissoc-with-pred [f m]
  (into {} (filter (fn [[k v]] (f k v)) m)))
```

test

```
(dissoc-with-pred (fn [k v] (> v 2)) {:a 2 :b 3 :c 1 :d 4})
=> {:b 3, :d 4}
```

Comment: You beat me to it! I was thinking on a similar solution

Comment: @murtaza52 I hope the answer was helpful.

Comment: Both of those start with a new empty map.  While this is often perfectly fine, it does mean that you might lose metadata or record type of the input map.  Actually using `dissoc` internally would fix that:
`(defn dissoc-with-pred [f m] (reduce-kv (fn [m k v] (if (f k v) m (dissoc m k))) m m))`